# Who is Julian Keller and why is X-23 so torn up about them?

Tags: marvel, comics, x-men, messiah-complex

During the final encounter with Lady Deathstryke, X-23 is 'let loose' on her and shouts about Julian Keller.

I don't recall anyone from the book called Julian, let alone then encountering Lady Deathstryke.

Who is this person, and why is X-23 so torn up about them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Julian Keller is better known as Hellion. The same Hellion who is critically injured by Lady Deathstryke when the New X-Men try to ambush the Purifiers.

As for why X-23 is so torn up, Hellion and X-23 may have a history of looking out for each other:

> New X-Men team. Just prior to the competition, Emma asked Julian to make sure that X-23 was eliminated early. However, when given the chance to knock her out, he saved her instead, because he owed her for doing the same during a session in the "Danger Cave".

...

> During the fight with Nimrod, X-23 was severely injured and was unable to heal herself. Hellion took it upon himself to rescue her by flying to the Institute

~ [Marvel Wikia](http://marvel.wikia.com/wiki/Julian_Keller_(Earth-616))

It's likely this closeness is one of the reason's why she seems so 'torn up'.

Comment: They also had something of a fling/romantic tension at the very least, although I can't remember if they ever outright went BF/GF.

Comment: @starpilotsix I avoided certain quotes from the wikia as I was also uncertain...

Comment: I need to go read more about myself sometime soon.